# How to prevent user from changing focus from View

Tags: android

In my android app I need to prevent user to change focus from current editText to any other view.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you please explain your need a little bit?

Comment: Have you tried view.setEnabled(false) on the Views you don't want focused, as well as view.setEnabled(true) for those you do?